# SQL query to relate 2 tables

Tags: sqlite

I want to relate following 2 tables in sqlite3. What I understood from other examples is that we should have some common field between each table, so I added order_ID.

1) How to write sqlite queries for creating the relation between these tables?

2) How to manage Table 2, where same order can have multiple products, so order ID is repeated. An order can have min 1 and max 10 products. So it has dynamic range of 1-10.

```
table 1:
order_ID  date   buyer  ship_chr  
001       01/01  abc    15        
002       05/01  xyz    10       

table 2:
order_ID  prod    quantity   rate
001       pen     50         2
001       paper   25         1
001       pin     50         2
002       paper   25         1
002       pen     100        2
```

Comment: I had an answer to your old version of this question, but then you deleted that question. Will you delete this question again?

Comment: @Corion you said last question was vague and after reading more about table relations I have put up my question in more simpler way. Anyways thanks for commenting there and here. I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: I also had a full answer that I was just about to post when you deleted your question, but I won't write things down again, sorry. Consider writing the proper SQL to create your tables first. And then read up on SQL `JOIN` clauses, they will solve the problem of correlating the tables for you.

Comment: @Corion don’t you feel it’s same question? Cause my problem is same there and here :D anyways thanks for help. I’ll read about Join clauses

Comment: I hope someone else would help me here

Comment: This is not a question; it's *three* questions.

Comment: @CL. I feel it’s all related. Please help me rephrase it if I’m missing something.

Comment: It's not; this would require three separate answers. Create three questions.

Comment: I have separated it into 2 questions. second one is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52796394/how-to-fetch-data-from-two-related-tables-and-put-in-3rd-table I hope you could help me with both. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to store orders and information about those orders. First, make an orders table.

```
create table orders (
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    created_at timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
    buyer text not null,
    ship_chr text not null
)
```

Note that instead of `order_id`, the primary key of a table is just `id`.
It's not required, but it is a convention I like as it keeps primary and foreign keys distinct.

Also note that I'm using the `timestamp` type to store dates, this will make working with those dates much easier as you can use [SQLite date functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Now we need a table for information about what is in each order.

```
create table order_products (
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    order_id integer not null references orders(id),
    product text not null,
    quantity integer not null,
    rate integer not null
)
```

This sets up a one-to-many relationship betweeen `orders` and `order_products`.
One order can have many `products`. You can link these tables together using
a [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). Here's how you'd get
the buyer for each product.

```
select o.buyer, op.product, op.quantity
from order_products op
join orders o on o.id = op.order_id

abc|pen|50
abc|paper|25
abc|pin|50
xyz|paper|25
xyz|pen|100
```

`join orders o on o.id = op.order_id` says for every row in `order_products` find one in `orders` where `order.id` matches the row's `order_id` and treat them both as a single row.

---

From here you'll probably want to make `products` and `buyer` their own tables
as well to store any information about the buyers and products. It also ensures
that the products and buyers exist avoiding typos.

```
create table buyers (
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    name text not null,
    address text not null,
    phone text not null
);

create table products (
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    name text not null,
    stock integer not null default 0
);    

create table orders (
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    created_at timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
    buyer_id integer references buyers(id) not null,
    ship_chr text not null
);

create table order_products (
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    order_id integer not null references orders(id),
    product_id integer not null references products(id),
    quantity integer not null,
    rate integer not null
);
```

Then you can join everything together to get information about products and buyers.

```
select b.name, p.name, op.quantity
from order_products op
join orders o on o.id = op.order_id
join buyers b on b.id = o.buyer_id
join products p on p.id = op.product_id

name|name|quantity
abc|pen|50
abc|paper|25
abc|pin|50
xyz|paper|25
xyz|pen|100
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/aa461/1/0)

If you don't do this now it will be harder to do later.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful and descriptive answer for a beginner like me.