# How to fetch data from two related tables and put in 3rd table

Tags: sql, sqlite

Total amount in Table 3 depends on Table1(Ship_chr) and multiple table2(quant*rate) entries.

what will be sqlite3 query for achieving this?

```
table 1:
order_ID  date   buyer  ship_chr  
001       01/01  abc    15        
002       05/01  xyz    10       

table 2:
order_ID  prod    quantity   rate
001       pen     50         2
001       paper   25         1
001       pin     50         2
002       paper   25         1
002       pen     100        2

table 3:
order_ID  total_amount
001       240
002       235
```

Comment: you know the best what you want, please show your effort spent so far before asking a question.

Comment: Yes, please provide the SQL you ave already tried. SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Could you show us the formula for `total_amount`?

Comment: @Schwern total amount  = quantity*rate + shipping charges. From table 2 I have to fetch multiple quantity*rate. I suppose Vishnu's answer will work, I'll check asap and accept the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for `total_amount` appears to be `rate * quantity` for each product + `ship_chr` (note: abbreviations make code difficult to understand).

Because each order has only one total price there's no need for a separate table. Instead, add a column to `orders`.

```
alter table orders add column total_price integer
```

Or you can calculate this on the fly. Using the [schema from my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52796777/14660)...

```
select sum(op.rate * op.quantity) + o.ship_chr
from order_products op
join orders o on o.id = op.order_id
group by op.order_id
```

The [`group by op.order_id`](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_groupby.asp) groups all the rows for the same order together. Then we can use the [aggregate function `sum`](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) to add up all the rows with the same order_id.

But then you have to ensure its kept up to date. You can do this for all orders with an `update` using the `select` to get the total price as a [subquery](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/understanding-sql-subqueries.php).

```
update orders
set total_price = (
    select sum(op.rate * op.quantity) + orders.ship_chr
    from order_products op
    where orders.id = op.order_id
    group by op.order_id
)
```

And as you add to an order you'll have to remember to also update the total. You can do this on the fly...

```
insert into order_products (order_id, product_id, quantity, rate) values
  (1, 1, 100, 3);

update orders
set total_price = total_price + (100 * 3)
where id = 1;
```

But it's probably safer to just recalculate the whole order after each change.

```
insert into order_products (order_id, product_id, quantity, rate) values
  (1, 1, 100, 3);

update orders
set total_price = (
    select sum(op.rate * op.quantity) + orders.ship_chr
    from order_products op
    where orders.id = op.order_id
    group by op.order_id
)
where id = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I added total_price to table1(orders) :)

Comment: What I understood is, while updating orders 'update orders' if i use 'join order_products op on orders.id = op.order_id' this will update whole table. Am i correct?

Comment: @user3170565 No, [you can't join on an `update` in SQLite](https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html). Instead, you do an `update` query to set `orders.total_price` and set it to the result of the `select` to get the total price for an order.

Comment: Suppose, I have inserted all values for 5 orders in ORDERS and ORDER_PRODUCTS table, then will following query update total_price for all 5 orders? or will i have to execute this query after every order entry `update orders
join order_products op on orders.id = op.order_id
set total_price = (
    select sum(op.rate * op.quantity) + orders.ship_chr
    from order_products op
    where orders.id = op.order_id
    group by op.order_id
)`  Thanks!

Comment: @user3170565 Sorry, I made a mistake and left a `join` in the `update`. Remove the `join` and it will work. It will update `total_price` for every order. You can make it a bit more efficient by adding `where id in (...)` where `...` is the list of IDs you just updated.

Answer (score 2):

You coud use inner  join , sum and group by

```
select a.order_ID, sum(a.quantity  * a.rate) + b.ship_chr as total_amount
from table2 a 
inner join table1 b on a.order_ID = b.order_ID
group by a.order_ID,  b.ship_chr
```

or using a suquery for the sum

```
select t1.order_ID, t1.tot + b.ship_chr total_amount
from table1 b
inner join (
    select a.order_ID, sum(a.quantity  * a.rate)  tot
    from table2 a 
    group by a.order_ID
) t1 on t1.order_ID = b.order_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need below

```
   INSERT INTO t3
   SELECT t1.order_ID, sum(t2.quantity*t2.rate)+t1.ship_chr as total_amount
   FROM table_1 t1 join table_2 t2 on t1.order_ID=t2.order_ID
   group by t1.order_ID,t1.ship_chr
```

Do join between two tables and use `sum()` aggregate function

Comment: (I think) you need to use `AVG(t1.ship_chr)`, else you will end up adding the `ship_chr` for every transaction! Also I think the query written as is will produce an error because you havent aggregated on `ship_chr`.

Comment: @VishnuKunchur There's no need to `avg(ship_chr)` because the one-order-to-many-products relationship guarantees there's only ever one `ship_chr` per `order_id`. The `+ t1.ship_chr` is outside an aggregate function so it's only applied once per aggregated row.

Answer (score 1):

Joining on `order_id`; `SUM(t2.prod * t2.quantity)` to get revenue by order_id, `AVG(ship_chr)` to add the `ship_chr` only once.

```
SELECT t2.order_id AS order_id, 
      SUM(t2.prod * t2.quantity) + AVG(t1.ship_chr) AS total_amount
FROM table2 t2 LEFT JOIN table1 t1
ON t2.order_id = t1.ordeR_id
GROUP BY t2.order_id
```

Comment: There's no need to `avg(t1.ship_chr)`. There's only one `ship_chr` per order.